# Django online users with rest framework

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I had used [django-online-users](https://pypi.org/project/django-online-users/) to get online users and it worked fine. But the problem is that i am not able to get online users in django rest framework i.e. users making api calls from react to backend server.

I am only getting direct logged in users log in admin panel.

Please suggest a way to use it with django rest framework.

Thanks.

Comment: That extension does its count based on sessions. The ReST frameswork usually does not use sessions for authentication.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I am using [link](https://pypi.org/project/drf-firebase-auth/) 'drf-firebase-auth' which uses jwt token authentication. Can you suggest a way to do online users count with token authentication. Thank you

Comment: @HarshRaj did you ever figure out a way around this? Having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you should import the online users models to use it

```py
from online_users.models import OnlineUserActivity
```

then you should use it in your custom APIView

```py
class OnlineUserAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        online_users = OnlineUserActivity.get_user_activities(time_delta=timedelta(minutes=2))
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(online_users, many=True)
        return response.Response(serialized_data.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

keep in mind you can determine the time delta which i set it 2 min.